# How to calculate the total VPN time on a network?

Tags: vpn

How can I calculate the total active connection time to a network? Ex. I work from home and when i do I create a VPN connection to my work network. I want to be able to let me boss see total of connection time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: VPN Status]

If you stay connected 24/7, you can claim 128 hours of overtime a week.